# Get gradle build type in product flavor

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to create different app names depending on the product flavour used.

While this was easy by simply setting a string resource, I can no longer do that because when the app is uploaded to hockeyapp the app name is set as '@string/app_name' instead of the value of app_name.

I have made some progress by setting the label in the manifest to be '${applicationName}' and setting the value with

```
manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationName : appName ];
```

in the product flavour block so that the value gets set at compile time.

The problem comes when I try to append the build type to the application name. I can't seem to find a way to know what build type is currently being used within the product flavour.

This is a stripped down version of the build for readability

```
android {
    buildVersionName "1.0.0

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ... nothing special
        }
        uat {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            buildType = "uat"
            applicationIdSuffix = "." + buildType
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            buildType = "uat"
            applicationIdSuffix = "." + buildType
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        flavor1{
            def appName = "app name " + buildType;
            manifestPlaceholders = [ applicationName : appName ];
            applicationId [id]
            def clientIteration = [client iteration]
            versionName buildVersionName + clientIteration
            versionCode [version code]
        }
        flavor2{
            ... same as above with different app name
        }
        flavor3{
            ... same as above with different app name
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine except the variable 'buildType' is always the last buildtype (in this case debug) which means the app name always has debug on the end.

Probably worth noting that I don't need to have anything appended on the end of the app name for releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late for the party but if you want different names based on the flavours, you should have something like this:

```
  productFlavors{
    flavour 1 {
        applicationId "your_app_id"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Flavour 1 app name"
        .......
    }

    flavour 2 {
        applicationId "your_app_id"
        resValue "string", "app_name", "Flavour 2 app name"
        .......

    }
}
```

and in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Brilliant, That will be useful for a stack of things thank you. I didn't know you could create resources via gradle.

Answer (score 6):

You can append the values like this

```
   android {

    productFlavors {
        Foo {
             applicationId "com.myexample.foo"
             manifestPlaceholders = [ appName:"Foo"]
        }

        Bar {
             applicationId "com.myexample.bar"
             manifestPlaceholders = [ appName:"Bar"]
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appNameSuffix:""]
        }

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appNameSuffix:".Debug"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

and in the manifest

```
<application
        android:label="${appName}${appNameSuffix}"
        ...
 </application>
```

If you want to access different values based on build type you can do it like this

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        buildConfigField "String", "Your_string_key", '"yourkeydebugvalue"'
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_URL", '"some text"'
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG", 'true'
    }
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "Your_string_key", '"yourkeyreleasevalue"'
        buildConfigField "String", "SOCKET_URL", '"release text"'
        buildConfigField "Boolean", "LOG", 'false'

    }
}
```

And to access those values using build variants:

```
 if(!BuildConfig.LOG)
      // do something with the boolean value
```

Or

```
view.setText(BuildConfig.yourkeyvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

This link http://inaka.net/blog/2014/12/22/create-separate-production-and-staging-builds-in-android/ may help you out.

If you have two productFlavors (Production and Staging, for instance)

You should create two different resource folders:

project/app/src/production/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="root_url">http://production.service.com/api</string>
</resources>
```

project/app/src/staging/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="root_url">http://staging.service.com/api</string>
</resources>
```

You should add this following code inside the android {}:

```
productFlavors {

    production {
        applicationId "com.inaka.app.production"
    }

    staging {
        applicationId "com.inaka.app.staging"
    }

}
```

It's a good idea to have different icons for different productFlavors, just add the icon inside each different resource folder.

Comment: Thanks Sibelius, No problems with the pointing to different end points. I'm using the build type for this and the product flavours are used for different clients.
This way I can have different environments setup for each client.
The problem is that I need the app name (android:label in manifest) set at compile time (can't use resource string) so that when the apps are loaded to hockeyapp the correct app name displays and not @string/app_name